# jQuery header scroll, how to offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at using a header scroll like the one here https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/, so when I scroll down the header retracts and when I scroll up it comes back into view.

HTML:

```
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}
main {
   background:url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}
footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
```

jQuery:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

This is almost exactly what I need, aside from a problem with an image about 500px high at the top of my homepage. I don't want the header to scroll up over the image, so when it gets to a position 500px from the top of the page I want it to retract.

I've played around with the code but I can't get it to do what I need, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you scroll down, the header is never visible. When you scroll up the header isn't visible between the top and the bottom of the image zone.

If you don't want to show the header the first 500px at all, remove `|| st < navbarHeight`.

```js
 if (st > 500 + navbarHeight || st < navbarHeight) {
   $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
 } else {
   $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
 }
```

**Demo**

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up 
    if (st > 500 + navbarHeight || st < navbarHeight) {
      $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    } else {
      $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
  top: -40px;
}

main {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
) repeat;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

* {
  color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
  This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
  <img src="" width="100%" height="500px" style="background-color:#ccc;" /> This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
  This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you NiZa, but this actually does the opposite of what I'm looking for. This keeps the header on show for the first 500px on scroll down. What I want is for the header to not show at all until the page is scrolled up, and then hide again when I get up to 500px from the top of the page (rather than coming down 500px from the top). So there's basically a 500px 'quiet zone' with no header at the top of the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I understand. You even dont want to show your header when scroll is on top? So the first 500px no header at all.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks! Removing  `|| st < navbarHeight` gives me what I'm after. The bar does appear on page load, before any scrolling takes place, but I'm sure I can figure that out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe exchange `st > navbarHeight` with `st > 500` ?

Comment: Thank you Björn, this does work, but it's as my answer to NiZa's response - this keeps the header in place for the first 500px.